# MYSQL Distinct values with totals

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

Trying to return a list of all of my users that have resolved a ticket and the number of tickets they resolved. **This code works**, but it seems bad practice to query inside of a while loop.

Is there a more efficient way?

```
//Get all users who have resolved a ticket
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT resolvedby FROM tickets");
$stmt->execute();

while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){
    $user = $rows['resolvedby'];
    echo "$user "; //Echo each user

    $new = $db->prepare("SELECT count(resolvedby) as total FROM tickets WHERE resolvedby = :u ");
    $new->bindParam('u',$user);
    $new->execute();

    $row = $new->fetch();
    echo $row['total']; //Echo the total of each user
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Returns:

```
User    Total Resolved
Shawn        40
David        38
Jeff         52
Frank        47
```

Comment: Use Group By to count

Comment: You are correct, almost always `query inside of a while loop` can be done another, more efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use group by with aggregate function count:

```
SELECT
      resolvedby
    , COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
    tickets
GROUP BY
    resolvedby
```

Sure, you'd like to limit results with some WHERE clause.